MPI error in miniconda prompt in base env
I installed MPI on my win10 for using mpi4py in python for some projects. everything was okay for a long time, but now I'm receiving following comments in anaconda prompt:
C:\Windows\system32>if not "C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\" == "" (
set "MSMPI_BIN=C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\"
set "MSMPI_BIN_CONDA_BACKUP="
else (set "MSMPI_BIN=" )

C:\Windows\system32>if not "" == "" (
set "MSMPI_INC="
set "MSMPI_INC_CONDA_BACKUP="
else (set "MSMPI_INC=" )

C:\Windows\system32>if not "" == "" (
set "MSMPI_LIB64="
set "MSMPI_LIB64_CONDA_BACKUP="
else (set "MSMPI_LIB64=" )

C:\Windows\system32>if not """" == "" (
set "MSMPI_LIB32="""
set "MSMPI_LIB32_CONDA_BACKUP="
> )

> (base) C:\Windows\system32>y

If i'm not mistaken it is happening after I moved file "msmpi.dll" from some folder, as some of packages instalation required.
How do i fix it? Should I just reinstall MPI?
I tried to change env in miniconda and there is no such problem, it is happening only in base.

It looks like this script is checking the existence of specific files related to the package. You need to check the source of the script to find out exactly which elements are missing, or not where they should be. For future reference you should never manually move package items after an install has been run. All of these packages rely on being installed at the locations set in the install script.
